# Why the name hypopharynx?

Tags: entomology, anatomy, nomenclature

Why the tongue (like structure) in cockroach (or other insects) is called hypopharynx? In humans I know it's the lower part of pharynx, not a structure. Isn't this anatomical name misleading? Are there other ambiguous terms like this?